# What causes: "Job failed (system failure): aborted: <nil>" in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Recently jobs started to randomly fail on my build server. Sometimes it happens on compilation step but sometimes as soon as

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (*hash*)
  on BUILDMACHINE01 *hash*
Using Shell executor...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): aborted: <nil>
```

My problem is my google searches for reason  didn't give ANY results. I also tried looking for some documentation of all errors from gitlab but couldn't find that either. Can someone shed some light on what could the problem be?

Comment: We also had this problem today - and the only fitting google result is this one. We might have to open a gitlab issue.

Answer (score 0):

One case when this is happening - it's when configuration directory comprising `config.toml` is a *symbolic link*.

At least this was my case.
Sure it's a bug.